# Speed up the analysis

Tags: performance, r, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes in R for example df and  dfrefseq.

```
df<-data.frame( chr =  c("chr1","chr1","chr1","chr4")
    , start = c(843294,4329248,4329423,4932234)
    , stop = c(845294,4329248,4529423,4935234)
    , genenames= c("HTA","OdX","FEA","MGA")
)
dfrefseq<-data.frame( chr =  c("chr1","chr1","chr1","chr2")
    , start = c(843294,4329248,4329423,4932234)
    , stop = c(845294,4329248,4529423,4935234)
    , genenames= c("tra","FGE","FFs","FAA")
)
```

I want to check for each gene in df witch gene in dfrefseq lies closest to the selected df gene.
I first selected "chr1" in both dataframes.
Then I calculated for the first gene in readschr1 the distance between start-start start-stop stop-start and stop-stop sites.
The sum of this calculations say everything about the distance. My question here is, How can I speed up this analyse? Because now I tested only 1 gene against a dataframe, but I need to test 2000 genes.

```
readschr1 <- subset(df,df[,1]=="chr1") 
refseqchr1 <- subset(dfrefseq,dfrefseq[,1]=="chr1") 

names<-list()
read_start_start<-list()
read_start_stop<-list() 
read_stop_start<-list()
read_stop_stop<-list()

for (i in 1:nrow(refseqchr1)) {
startstart<-abs(readschr1[1,2] - refseqchr1[i,2])
startstop<-abs(readschr1[1,2] - refseqchr1[i,3])
stopstart<-abs(readschr1[1,3] - refseqchr1[i,2])
stopstop<-abs(readschr1[1,3] - refseqchr1[i,3])
read_start_start[[i]]<- matrix(startstart)
read_start_stop[[i]]<- matrix(startstop)
read_stop_start[[i]]<- matrix(stopstart)
read_stop_stop[[i]]<- matrix(stopstop)
names[[i]]<-matrix(refseqchr1[i,4])
}
table<-cbind(names, read_start_start, read_start_stop, read_stop_start, read_stop_stop)


sumtotalcolumns<-as.numeric(table[,2]) + as.numeric(table[,3])+ as.numeric(table[,4]) + as.numeric(table[,5])
test<-cbind(table, sumtotalcolumns)
test1<-test[order(as.vector(test$sumtotalcolumns)), ]
```

Thank you!

Comment: note that `df` is a function in R. I'd try and avoid using it if possible in the future. `dat` is a good name to use IMHO. Same with `table` and `names`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `merge` the two separate data.frames together to form one table and then use vectorized operations. The key to `merge` is to specify the common column(s) between the data.frames and to tell it what to do when there are cases that do not match. Specifying `all = TRUE` will return all rows and fill in NAs if there is no match in the other data.frame, i.e. ch2 and ch4 in this case. Once the data.frames have been merged, then it's a simple exercise in subtracting the different columns from one another and then summing the four columns of interest. I use `transform` to cut down on the typing needed to do the subtraction.

```
zz <- merge(df, dfrefseq, by = "chr", all = TRUE)

zz <- transform(zz, 
    read_start_start = abs(start.x - start.y)
  , read_start_stop = abs(start.x - stop.y)
  , read_stop_start = abs(stop.x - start.y)
  , read_stop_stop = abs(stop.x - stop.y)
)

zz <- transform(zz,
  sum_total_columns = read_start_start + read_start_stop + read_stop_start + read_stop_stop
  )
```

Here's one approach get the row with the minimum distance. I'm assuming you want to do this by chr and genenames. I use the `plyr` package, but I'm sure there are base solutions if you'd prefer one of those. Maybe someone else will chime in with a base solution.

```
require(plyr)
ddply(zz, c("chr", "genenames.x"), function(x) x[which.min(x$sum_total_columns) ,])
```

Comment: Dear Chase, Many thanks for you solution. He works for my dataset. The only thing is that my data zz is very large. Do you know if it's is possible to save only the result with the lowest sum_total_culomns. I thought something with the unique function.

Comment: @Lisann - Added to my answer to address your additional question.

Comment: You can change all = TRUE in merge to all.x = TRUE and gain some speedup.

Answer (score 4):

The Bioconductor package `GenomicRanges` is designed to work with this type of data

```
source('http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R')
biocLite('GenomicRanges')                      # one-time installation
```

then

```
library(GenomicRanges)
gr <- with(df,
           GRanges(factor(chr, levels=paste("chr", 1:4, sep="")),
                   IRanges(start, stop), genenames=genenames))
grrefseq <- with(dfrefseq,
                 GRanges(factor(chr, levels=paste("chr", 1:4, sep="")),
                         IRanges(start, stop), genenames=genenames))
```

and

```
> nearest(gr, grrefseq)
[1]  1  2  3 NA
```